# showing full nav-bar in small screens

Tags: jquery, html, css

While clicking on the cross button navbar is visible however in small-screens navbar is not `1000px`as `html overflow is hidden`.How can i show full height of navbar without removing overflow:hidden for the image part
This is my code:

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
  $('#nav').show();
  $('img').hide();
})
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
#nav{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  background:#454545;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="start"><h3>&#9747;</h3>
  <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/E0z7vJl.jpg">
</header>
<div id="nav"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you chose `height: 1000px`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

You Can see https://jsfiddle.net/ag0vcn4h/2/

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
  $('#nav').show();
  $('img').hide();
})
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
#nav{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width:100%;
  background:#454545;
  display:none;
  height:calc(100vh - 70px) // 70 px is your header height you can change
}
#nav2{
   height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="start"><h3>&#9747;</h3></div>
  <img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/E0z7vJl.jpg">
</header>
<div id="nav">
   <div id="nav2">

   </div>

</div>
```

EDIT:

Add #nav inside a div#nav2 and change #nav height for scren.
      #nav{ overflow-y:scroll; }
      #nav2{height:1000px}